# Convert string to byte array in frida js script

Tags: javascript, frida

I am having an issue with a JavaScript script to be executed in Frida. In this case, I am intercepting an input from a function where I receive an array of bytes. I need to convert this array to a string, modify it, and then convert it back to an array of bytes before returning the value.

I managed to make the first step work correctly, which is converting the array of bytes into a string and modifying the string. However, the problem arises when I try to convert the string back into an array of bytes; it throws an error. I tried using the Java native function getBytes(), but it gives the error below:

```
TypeError: not a function
```

My code is:

```
//result is byte[]
let StringJava = Java.use("java.lang.String");
var json = StringJava.$new(result);
try {
  let arg1 = StringJava.$new(": 0,");
  let arg2 = StringJava.$new(": 1000,");
  json = json.replace(arg1,arg2);
  let newByte = json.getBytes(); //error in line
  return newByte;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error:", error);
}
```

Is there a simple way for me to convert this string back into an array of bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem of your code seems to that frida wants to help you too much:

Before you call `json = json.replace(arg1,arg2);` json is an instance of the Java type `java.lang.String`.

When you assign the return value of the `replace` method to `json`,  frida seems to automatically convert the Java String to a JavaScript string (I assume for convenience).

If you then try to call `getBytes()` on the JavaScript string it fails because JavaScript strings don't have this method. As workaround you could change the line to `json = StringJava.$new(json).getBytes()`, however that would require a lot of unnecessary conversions.

In the end I would recommend to do the whole string replacement with JavaScript code and only for calling `getBytes()` make it a Java string.

My complete and working test script is this:

```
Java.perform(() => {

    function test(result) {
        let StringJava = Java.use("java.lang.String");
        var json = String(result); // may be unnecessary, just to make sure json is a JavaScript string
        try {
            let arg1 = ": 0,";
            let arg2 = ": 1000,";
            json = json.replace(arg1, arg2);
            return StringJava.$new(json).getBytes();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error:", error);
        }
    }

    var bytes = test('{ "a": 0, "b": 1 }');
    // do something with bytes

});
```